# Foreach, extension methods, and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, foreach, extension-methods, enumerable

Just a quick question out of curiosity. So according to the MSDN documentation regarding foreach loop, it implements System.Collections.IEnumerable. There is also a warning in the documentation that you can't modify the collection while using a foreach loop (I'm assuming foreach loops aren't very thread safe in this regard?)

**Documentation**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Also, out of curiosity, is a foreach loop more optimized than a for loop in terms of speed? I know a foreach loop is easier to type/read, but does it execute faster than a for loop?

Looking at the MSDN documentation for a list, the extension method, Average, is defined by Enumerable. What does the documentation mean when it says it performs a transform function on each element?
Does this mean the extension method behaves similarly to a foreach loop? 
**Documentation**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549067(v=vs.110).aspx

Hypothetically speaking, let's say I have two threads. Let's say I have a List shared by these two threads. The first thread is traversing through this list (foreach) and the second thread is using the Average extension method on this list. So will this cause an exception to be thrown? I'm aware any potential problems can be avoided by using locks, but for discussion sake, let's assume I'm not using locks.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looping over the list and `Average()` both only read from from the list, so this will not cause an exception. The speed of `foreach` depends on how `GetEnumerator()` is implemented.

Comment: Have you tried running some benchmarks? You can't change the collection while you're working on it, that's not related to thread safe but, for example, if you do a for and remove the last item, you'll be getting a stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe its just typos but you seem to have a misconception of what a foreach loop does.  The loop itself does not implement `IEnumerable`, it only allows _objects_ that implement `IEnumerable` to be iterated on.  The part about modifying the collection while looping is not a thread safety issue, its because the loop is iterating over the collection, if the collection is changing how could you reasonably iterate it?

Comment: If you read carefully in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you will see that SO is not really a place for "assume" and "hypothetically speaking". Show us your code with a problem - or test stuff yourself.

Comment: Just a correction, I don't remember the exactly exception but you can see it for yourself. ;)

Comment: I'm still new to programming, and I really appreciate your clarifications! Can one of you guys make an answer to the question so I can select it as "best answer" and give you the rep you deserve? @PatrickArtner: My bad. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Tim the "question" is too broad and will be closed anyway

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad, Tim. I think you could put some more effort on it and break it into two separated questions. You can check IEnumerable and Thread Safe Collections. Also write some code testing your assumptions. You'll learn a lot and ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So according to the MSDN documentation regarding foreach loop, it implements System.Collections.IEnumerable

No. Anything that supports a `GetEnumerator()` method that in turn returns an object that supports a `bool MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property will support `foreach`. `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` both support that and hence everything that implements them will allow for `foreach`, but it's not the only way. It is though not only a convenient way but also a way that can be used with methods that take an `IEnumerable<T>` including the linq extension methods, so it's generally best to take that approach when you want to support `foreach`. (You might choose to **also** support another means like `List<T>` does, but it's rarely worth it).

> Also, out of curiosity, is a foreach loop more optimized than a for loop in terms of speed?

That's complicated because it's a matter of `foreach` on what vs `for` on what. It's common for `for` to have the edge as it involves a few less virtual calls, but there are exceptions when `foreach` is faster. For added complication if you were acting directly on an array then `foreach` would be slower except the compiler actually catches this and rewrites it as a `for` behind the scenes for you so they are exactly the same.

> What does the documentation mean when it says it performs a transform function on each element.

It means that that particular overload of `Average` passes each element to a call to the `selector` passed to it. It is the result of this *transform* that is averaged.

> Does this mean the extension method behaves similarly to a foreach loop?

Yes. Indeed they often are `foreach`. That particular method is a `foreach` in the .NET Framework version and a slight optimisation upon `foreach` in the .NET Core version. Many methods are `foreach` in both versions. Some methods use `for` in a few cases where it's known to be more performant (see above about how this is sometimes the case and sometimes not). Much of the optimisations that are done wouldn't be worth it in the vast majority of the case, but the Linq methods are heavily used by a lot of people, so the effort to optimise even a little pays off.

> The first thread is traversing through this list (foreach) and the second thread is using the Average extension method on this list. So will this cause an exception to be thrown?

In this particular case as long as no thread writes to the list the two will not cause each other any problems. The objects used to implement `foreach` are created separately in each thread and they are the only objects that mutate. This is not guaranteed by the documentation for `List<T>`, but unlikely to change.

This does not hold for everything that supports `foreach` though. There's no promise around multi-threaded `foreach` except where a given implementation makes it.